# Null Pointer Exception When Incrementing Variable

Tags: apex, null-pointer

I'm getting a Null Pointer Exception in a utility method I wrote to update some contacts. What can I do to prevent a null pointer exception when I modify this field?

```
public void AddEL()
{
    //select the id and the earned Leave field to be auto-incremented
    List<Contact> lstcontact = [SELECT Id, Test_Earned_Leave__c FROM Contact];

    // run the for loop and update the earned leave field value
    for(Contact con : lstcontact)
    {   
        Con.Test_Earned_Leave__c = Con.Test_Earned_Leave__c + 1.25;
    } 

    update lstcontact;
}
```

Comment: This code looks dangerous to me. There is no error checking within it, to determine whether or not it has already been run. What if a coding error or other issue causes it to be called more than once?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before adding , we have to check whether that variable is null.

```
public void AddEL()
{
    List<Contact> lstcontact = [SELECT Id,Test_Earned_Leave__c FROM Contact];

    for(Contact con : lstcontact)
    {
        if(con.Test_Earned_Leave__c == null)
        {
            Con.Test_Earned_Leave__c =1.25;
        }
        else
        {
            Con.Test_Earned_Leave__c = Con.Test_Earned_Leave__c+1.25;
        }
    }

    update lstcontact;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

This code will treat a null value as the same as a zero value and avoid the exception:

```
if (Con.Test_Earned_Leave__c != null) Con.Test_Earned_Leave__c += 1.25;
else Con.Test_Earned_Leave__c = 1.25;
```

Answer (score 2):

Please try this code in your loop:

```
if (Con.Test_Earned_Leave__c != null) {
    Con.Test_Earned_Leave__c += 1.25;
} else {
    Con.Test_Earned_Leave__c = 1.25;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @maovrn have tried the code and seems to work will schedule for future runs and let you know.